# Frozen sea squirts: any suggests on cleaning/preparing?

Tags: seafood

I bought a pack of frozen sea squirts from Korean market. They are quite small - 3-4 cm long creatures. I dug all possible recipes about sea squirts, but all of them are about either alive or dried sea squirts. Can you please recommend how to clean them and prepare for cooking?

My current idea is to unfreeze them, wash intensively, and ultimately cook (uncut) in a medium intensity sauce for 10 minutes.

Comment: Haha I found this, it's an amusing read :) http://oddfooddude.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/sea-squirt.html

Comment: still ) the unfrozen one have yellow/brown liquid... and smell is intense...

Answer (score 1):

Small world, just defrosted my pack of 4cm ers. Peel skin, cut in half, cut out liver, rinse well in cold water, slather in your favorite hot sauce for your first one! Then be creative from there or throw the rest down the toilet, its a very acquired taste!

Meonggeboy